# PHP - access creator class' properties when constructing new class

Tags: php, class, oop

I am trying to create the following setup:

```
class Car {
    public $brochure;
    public function getBrochure() {
        $this->brochure = new Brochure();
    }
}

class Jeep extends Car {
    ...
    public $terrain = 'dirt';
}

class SportsCar extends Car {
    ...
    public $terrain = 'racing tracks';
}
```

Then, I want to have the brochure class:

```
class Brochure {
    public $advertisement_text;
    public function __construct() {
        ...
        if($terrain) {
            $str = $str ."This car is best driven on $terrain!\r\n";
        }
        ...
        $this->advertisement_text = $str;
    }
}
```

Obviously, the `$terrain` variable doesn't exist. I could always pass it down as an argument, but I am wondering if it is possible to access the creator class' public properties without passing them down?

Comment: The problem of accessing other classes  properties is that it starts to increase the dependencies between the classes, sometimes the references almost become circular as two classes call each other so much that any changes can break this system.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Still, I would like to just know how to do that, if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to pass in the variables in the constructor, I've changed a few things (I've added comments to the code were applicable)...

```
class Brochure {
    public $advertisement_text;
    // Create brochure with the terrain
    public function __construct( $terrain ) {
        $str = "This car is best driven on $terrain!\r\n";
        $this->advertisement_text = $str;
    }
}

class Car {
    public $brochure;
    public $terrain = '';
    public function getBrochure(  ) {
        // Only set value if not already set
        if ( $this->brochure == null ){
            // Pass the terrain from the current object creating the brochure
            $this->brochure = new Brochure($this->terrain);
        }
        // Return the brochure created
        return $this->brochure;
    }
}

class Jeep extends Car {
    public $terrain = 'dirt';
}

class SportsCar extends Car {
    public $terrain = 'racing tracks';
}

$car = new SportsCar();
$brochure = $car->getBrochure();
echo $brochure->advertisement_text;
```

This outputs...

```
This car is best driven on racing tracks!
```

It can get really complicated if you need a whole load of data for your brochure, sometimes using a different method may give more future proofing, but this should be a start.

Comment: Thank you Nigel. I can understand why you would use this method for such a task. I am curious to know how else this can be done. In your comment you mentioned dependencies, I can see how it could become a problem. Nevertheless, what are some options there? As you said this method can become cumbersome with lots of data, so I'm eager to know more

Answer (score 0):

```
When you create object of Brochure class pass argument of SportsCar class object like this:

class Brochure {
    public $advertisement_text;
    public function __construct($SportsCar) {
        ...
        if($terrain) {

            $str = $str ."This car is best driven on $SportsCar->$terrain!\r\n";
        }
        ...
    $this->advertisement_text = $str;
}


    $SportsCar=new $SportsCar();
    $Brochure =new $Brochure($SportsCar);
```